# Odd dropdown/select behavior in phonegap on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ipad, ionic-framework

We have a phonegap/ionic application targeting iOS. We have been testing with the ipad air simulator (xcode) and ipad air (10.3.3), ipad Pro (11.0.3).

The app is an ionic (v1) app that downloads and loads stand alone html files (the files contain css, html, js in one doc). The documents are typically long forms. In all test environments we are getting odd behavior with selects/drop downs.

When you click/tap on a select the options will appear correctly. 
[image]

Then when you click/tap somewhere else, blank space or another input field you will usually get the select options bubble again but it will be empty. 
[image]

In the above image I made my selection from the options and then clicked into the next field.

This was intermittent at first and now it seems to happen all the time. It seems like it has something to do with losing focus but I am unable to see why this is popping back up. I haven't found anything very useful from searching online in regards to this problem.

**UPDATE** **11/7/17**

After more thorough searching this seems to be due to building the app with xcode 9 and/or the use of UIWebView vs WKWebview. I also looked through the code more to see we were already using WKWebView not UIWebView and the problem is still present. As someone mentioned in [this thread](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13287).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having same experience when using select lists in a new release. Never happened before latest build.

Answer (score 0):

Good thing is Cordova has support for WKWebView too. You have to install the plugin: **cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine**

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with more info regarding us already using WKWebView.